# Nested Quotes in PHP

Tags: php, syntax, quotes, gnu-screen

I'm having another problem with the quotes in PHP, I have two sets of nested quotes inside a normal set and this is what I thought should work

```
 if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, 'screen -p 0 -S new3 -X eval \"stuff \"stop\"\015\"'))) {
```

This is how it is in just a simple bash script:

```
screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval 'stuff \"stop\"\015'
```

So I need help getting it from bash to working in PHP, thanks!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Minecraft, I suppose?

Comment: @minitech: I guess, but the actual question itself is about as far removed from Java as one can imagine.

Comment: @HovercraftFullofEels, Sorry about that, I was thinking to fast and I put java for exactly that reason, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape the escape character, like so:

```
if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, 'screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval \'stuff \\"stop\\"\\015\''))) {
```

too many quoting though, and you get the [leaning toothpick problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

Comment: Ahh! So close, it is sending the command to the minecraft session but it is sending "stop" (WITH quotes) instead of just stop (WIHTOUT quotes) lol, what could be the cause for that?